# How I can know which imports add in project.json?

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-standard, project.json

In project.json now we can specify different frameworks. Now the complexity is increased due to the several options to target.
You may fill `framework`, `runtime` and `dependencies` fields making the system much more flexible but so much complex too specially now that exist a new target called `netstandard`.

Each framework and dependency can have other fields too, one that takes my attention is `import`. I have seen different examples using differently but I dont know its effect. In addition I have run in trouble playing with that.

Can someone turn one light about that?

Answer (score 0):

The `imports` property is used when you want to reference some packages that don't seem to be compatible with the current framework, but you know that they actually are.

This is mostly useful when your framework is `netcoreapp` or `netstandard` and you want to reference a package that doesn't have a `netstandard` version yet, but either has a version that uses an old version of .Net Core (`dnxcore50`, but such packages should be very rare now) or has a PCL version (`portable-*`).

If you're not in such situation, you should not use `imports`. You definitely can run into trouble if you use it improperly, it's there for those "I know what I'm doing, trust me" cases.